# Can electric field lines form a closed loop in my hypothetical object

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

While reading a book of physics, I got a line which it says that electric field lines never form a loop.
After this I was Imagining all the type of cases, In which I thought of a hypothetical case which I will describe below.

Imagine a hypothetical sphere made up of two hemispheres each of opposite charge. The sphere is made such that the hemispheres touch each other but do not neutralize(I know it seems impossible).
Now if we draw electric field lines of them we get a loop like structure in magnet.
I just want to ask that if it was possible would it be considered as a closed loop?
Remember its just my imagination

Also I am in 10th grade so I do not many advanced concepts, sorry for a silly doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly your Point is incomplete(As I understand you are just in you 10th grade), But electric fields can form closed loops!!
But only under a very specific case which you will not study(Actually you will but you will learn it's application, The application-Generator and motor where we are told that a time varying magnetic feild induces a current in the loop.) Just to be very specific ,The nature of electric field is governed by these laws:
$$
\nabla \cdot \vec{E}=\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_o}
$$
and
$$
\nabla \times \vec{E}=-\frac{\partial{\vec{B}}}{\partial{t}}
$$
You will learn these equation in your 11th and 12th classes. **So Electric field can exist without charge or in your language Electric field can form closed loop.**
Now for your case we can use an insulator with some charge sepration.(It is not soooo hypothetical, Even we derive the electric field expression for fields like these. Trust me it's pretty cumbersome but doable).In your case What will happen is that The electric field will emerge from the positive charge and terminate at the negative charge. So indeed it will not form closed loop.It might look like that but it isn't.
**Just remeber this: "Electric field can form closed loop only when charges are not present!"**.
I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

So we can imagine a hollow sphere where the north hemisphere is positively charged and the south negatively charged. The field outside will be roughly a [dipole field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole), with electric field lines forming a curve from a point on the north hemisphere to the corresponding point below it on the south hemisphere. If the sphere is hollow there will also be field line between the points inside it... but it will go from north to south too. So while there is a closed loop the field points in different directions in different parts of it.

This is important, since if you had a positively charged particle start at the surface and move along the field line outside the sphere it would gain energy. Were it to also be able to follow the interior field line back to where it started it would now have gained even more energy and be able to repeat the journey, extracting infinite energy. That doesn't happen: the interior field line points in the opposite direction and it would cost energy for the particle to move along it.

The deep reason is that the electrical potential makes the electric field [conservative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field): moving around a loop will always leave you with the same energy. Charges acts as sources and sinks of the potential, but since it is conservative their presence do not matter for the overall conservation of energy. But conservative fields are gradients of a scalar function, and that means they do not form complete, unidirectional loops.